# postgres-9.4 claims data directory is missing, when it isn't

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-initdb

I'm having trouble starting postgresql-9.4 on Centos 6.

I can't run `initdb` because the data directory already exists.

But I can't start the service because the data directory is missing!

```
[centos@dave-gbp ~]$ sudo service postgresql-9.4 start

/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data is missing. Use "service postgresql-9.4 initdb" to initialize the cluster first.
                                                       [FAILED]
[centos@dave-gbp ~]$ sudo service postgresql-9.4 initdb
Initializing database: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log': File exists
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Any idea how I can get past this problem?

Comment: what is the output of  `ls -la` for `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data` ? if data is empty try to delete `/data` folder and re-init database

Comment: I deleted 'data' and afterwards was able to `initdb` and then start the service.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very easy for initdb.

1. Use cd /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data
   In Which Two files 1.pg_log, 2.postgresql.conf
2. remove both using rm -rf .
3. Then exit from all directory.
4. use command "/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-setup initdb" for initialze db